# Stripe elements style setting in css

Tags: javascript, angularjs, stripe-payments

I can set styles in the style options object for stripe

```
var elementStyles = {
    base: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontWeight: 400,
        fontSize: '12px',
        color: '#333'
    }
};
          
var stripe = stripeElements.elements();

cardNumberStripeElement = stripe.create('cardNumber', {
    styles: elementStyles
});
```

But I want to transfer styles to css.
This example does not apply my styles, only those that apply to the container

```
var elementClasses = {
    base: 'card-info-base'
};
var stripe = stripeElements.elements();

cardNumberStripeElement = stripe.create('cardNumber', {
    classes: elementClasses
});
```

in css

```
.card-info-base {
    text-align: center "does not work";
    font-weight: 400 "does not work";
    font-size: 12px "does not work";
    height: 100px "works"
}
```

**How do i transfer styles to css?**

Comment: Can you see which styles are applied last in the console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a good question. Unfortunately, it's not possible to apply those styles to the card element in the way you're thinking. The reason is that the card input is embedded within an iframe and *styles don't cascade from a parent window down into iframes*.

When you add a class to the `classes` option, the class gets added to the element that you mounting the card in. For example, this is roughly what the DOM would look like once the element has mounted in your case:

```html
<div id="card-element" class="card-info-input StripeElement--empty">
  <div class="__PrivateStripeElement">
   <iframe src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/">
      #document
      <input class="InputElement">
   </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, any styles that are applied by `card-info-input` wouldn't make their way down to the actual input because its in an iframe.

This is different when you use the `style` option [0]. When you add a custom style using the `style` option that style is automatically added to the `InputElement` class when the card mounts. In a way, styles added through the `style` option are injected into the iframe by Stripe.js - this is why they work the way you expect.

#### TLDR;

If you want to apply styles to the `input` inside the iframe use the `style` option [0]. If you want to apply styles to card's parent element you can use the `classes` option [1] - this is especially useful if you want to apply different styles depending on the state of the input (focused, invalid, etc.)

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=card#elements_create-options-style

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=card#elements_create-options-classes

Comment: I figured out whats going on before searching on stackoverflow, but simply inspecting the DOM. However, in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvnxd1xne7Q Andrew Schmelyun adds the card element to a form (starts 38:00) , uses the CLASSES attribute, and then at 43:46 the stripe element gets the same styling as the rest of his form. Somehow his classes to make their way down to the input element... any idea how?